# Python: Web Scraping Attribute Error (Resultset)

Tags: python, web, web-scraping

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
import requests

url = 'https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Main_Page'
r = requests.get(url)

Soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html5lib")
List = Soup.find("div",class_="enws-mainpage-widget-content", id="enws-mainpage-newtexts-content").find_all('a')
ebooks=[]
i=0
for ebook in List:
    x=ebook.get('title')
    for ch in x:
        if(ch==":"):
            x=""
    if x!="":
        ebooks.append(x)
        i=i+1
        

inputnumber=0
while inputnumber<len(ebooks):
    print(inputnumber+1, " - ", ebooks[inputnumber])
    inputnumber=inputnumber+1
input=int(input("Please select a book: "))
selectedbook = Soup.find("a", title=ebooks[input-1])
print(selectedbook['title'])
url1 = "https://en.wikisource.org/"+selectedbook['href']
r1 = requests.get(url1)
Soup1 = BeautifulSoup(r1.text, "html5lib")
List1 = Soup1.find_all("div", class_="prp-pages-output").find_all('p')
words=str(List1)
ebook1= open('ebook1.txt', 'w', encoding="utf-8")
ebook1.write(words)
ebook1.close()
```

I'm trying to download an e-book selected by user from this website:'https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Main_Page'

Everything is fine until when I try to get the paragraghs from the selected book.
I get this error on List1 line:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "homework.py", line 32, in <module>
    List1 = Soup1.find_all("div", class_="prp-pages-output").find_all('p')
  File "C:\Users\Özdal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 2173, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

If I change it to this:

```
List1 = Soup1.find("div", class_="prp-pages-output").find_all('p')
```

Code only gives me first div but I need all of the divs. What should I do?

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at a style guide like [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 0):

The following will give you a list of lists

```
List1 = [x.find_all('p') for x in Soup1.find_all("div", class_="prp-pages-output")]
```

You can then flatten like so

```
flat_list1 = [item for sublist in List1 for item in sublist]
```